# Fade between two different SKTextures on SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sktexture

Does anyone know if there is a way to fade (over time) between two different `SKTexture`s on an `SKSpriteNode`. I am assuming that you can't do this directly and plan to use a duplicate child sprite with a higher `ZPosition` to realise the fade, but I just wanted to check that there was not some method using `SKAction`(s) that I had over looked.

Comment: yup, use two sprites and cross-fade them

Answer (score 2):

The following code should address this issue assuming the new texture fits overtop of the old one (it doesn't fade *out* the previous texture, but simply fades *in* the new one on top).  I've left out minor implementation details such as timing mode.

```
-(void) fadeTexture:(SKTexture *)newTexture ontoSpriteNode:(SKSpriteNode *)referenceSpriteNode withDuration:(CFTimeInterval)duration {

    SKSpriteNode * fadeInSprite = [self fadeInSpriteWithTexture:newTexture referenceSpriteNode:referenceSpriteNode];

    [[referenceSpriteNode parent] addChild:fadeInSprite];
    [fadeInSprite runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
        [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:1 duration:duration],
        [SKAction runBlock:^{
            [fadeInSprite removeFromParent];
            [referenceSpriteNode setTexture:newTexture];
        }]
    ]]];
}

-(SKSpriteNode *) fadeInSpriteWithTexture:(SKTexture *)newTexture referenceSpriteNode:(SKSpriteNode *)referenceSpriteNode {

    SKSpriteNode * fadeInSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:newTexture size:[referenceSpriteNode size]];
    [fadeInSprite setAlpha:0];
    [fadeInSprite setAnchorPoint:[referenceSpriteNode anchorPoint]];
    [fadeInSprite setPosition:[referenceSpriteNode position]];
    return fadeInSprite;
}
```